# Javascript - What will be the most efficient between these two techniques?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a little confettis generator in Javascript (and jQuery).
I'll use setInterval() to increase top position of each confetti every 0.06s and  I wonder : what will be the most efficient / the most performant technique between technique A and technique B, below ?

---

Technique A : thousands confettis but 1 confetti = 1 individual setInterval() for setting its top position :

```
for(var i=0; i<confettisQty; i++)
{
    var confetti = document.createElement("div");
    confetti.css("top","-100px");
    $("body").appendChild(confetti);

    setInterval(function(){
        var newTopPosition = confetti.position().top + 10;
        confetti.css("top", newTopPosition);
    },
    60);
}
```

Technique B : thousands confettis but 1 global setInterval() which goes look after every confetti and then change top position of each one :

```
for(var i=0; i<confettisQty; i++)
{
    var confetti = document.createElement("div");
    confetti.addClass("littleConfetti");
    confetti.css("top","-100px");
    $("body").appendChild(confetti);
}

setInterval(function(){
    $(".littleConfetti").each(function(){
        var newTopPosition = $(this).position().top + 10;
        $(this).css("top", newTopPosition);
    });
},
60);
```

I'm learning Javascript language and I'm looking for the best practices and techniques in terms of optimization and performance. So if you could please give me some explanations with your answer, it would be very apreciated!

Comment: that's going to be slowish, at least cache your JQ collections. the 2nd one is faster. CSS animation would be much smoother and less CPU and code heavy. just define `.littleConfetti{ position: absolute; top: -100px; transition: 1000ms top;}` then, append first, then set css's top to 500 (or whatever); it will slowly and smoothly "fall" and you won't need the 2nd half of js

Comment: Ok, thanks! Indeed, I didn't think about this alternative with CSS3. I've just tryed that and it seems to be a true solution. In particular if you tell it's less CPU consuming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are mixing JS and JQuery, in your code you should change

```
confeti.css(), confeti.position()
```

to

```
$(confeti).css(), $(confeti).position()
```

Since you need a JQuery object

**Edit:**

Due to the Dandavis comment, I made a deeper search and I have to say that  he is right, after reading several articles they all confirm his theory. So I made some tests to the code to find which code has a better performance.

At the beginning I thought that the second option will be better, since that it only create a `setInterval`, but I could find that I was totally wrong.

The cost of the `setInterval` is insignificant in compared to the costs of the JQuery `.littleConfetti` selector. The Option B is very slow in the first execution of the interval, that's because it's the first time that search for the `.littleConfetti` elements, the following times that the interval is executed, the execution time drops dramatically, although not enough to beat the Option A.

I executed each test 20 times and all the times are in milliseconds. The test results are:

**confettisQty = 1000**

- Option A: 144
- Option B: 240(first time)/130(following times)

**confettisQty = 10000**

- Option A: 695
- Option B: 21278(first time)/ 1134(following times)

**confettisQty = 100000**

- Option A: 12725
- Option B: 946740(first time)/10568(following times)

So, after the tests we can say that Option A was better. In spite of that the CSS option will perform better.

Comment: JS is single threaded. period. it does take work to schedule and recall an interval, but nowhere near as much overhead as a whole thread has.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The attached answer is indeed interesting. So I will take tech B (or maybe CSS3 solution, proposed by dandavis). Thank by the way about the JS/jQuery mixing. I thought I could do that.

Comment: @Ivan : it's a nice and really appreciated test ! Thank you !